# Script for optimizing images for web

Tags: php, image, optimization

In PHP, imagecreatefromjpeg() can optimize an image, as it saves the image with an appropriate quality for web. However, this is not the best option. I optimized again the php-generated image by [Yahoo Smush](http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/) and it optimized the image by a factor of 5-10%. This is not strange indeed; but alternatively I used http://www.imageoptimizer.net/ and it optimized my php-generated images by a factor of more than 50%.

This is indeed a significant improvement to save bandwidth and fast load of the webpages. I wonder what technology they use. They offer a windows-based application, but no description about their method.

Anyway, my question is how we can make a script (in php, perl, python, etc) to optimize to this extent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about those algorithms involved for compressing and optimizing images, but i would believe, that they would get too slow, if implemented in pure PHP. I therefore would recommend using already available command-line tools and wrap them in a PHP class or script. Some of these tools are:

- PNG: [optipng](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/), [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/index.html)
- JPG: [jpgcrush](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2942348) (i am unable to find any website for this)